# Why is U-238 detrimental for nuclear bomb？

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, isotopes

I know U-238 is more stable than U-235, because it is an even-even nucleus. Only neutron with energy larger than 1.6Mev can split an U-238, while any neutron can split U-235.

But why is the presence of the U-238 detrimental for the chain reaction of the U-235? Is it absorbing the neutrons without giving out neutrons? Or roughly speaking, U-238 is some black hole for the neutrons? If U-238 is not absorging neutrons, but just colliding with the neutrons, their presence should be okay?

Comment: Find your local ENDF mirror and look at the neutron cross sections for various neutron reactions vs energy for the two nuclei.

Comment: But, yes, U-238 is a black hole for lower energy neutrons…

Answer (score 1):

**First Three Questions:**

Wikipedia's introduction to [Uranium-$238$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238) might help:

> Uranium-$238$ [...]. Unlike uranium-$235$, it is non-fissile, which means it cannot sustain a chain reaction in a thermal-neutron reactor. However, it is [...] fertile, meaning it can be transmuted to fissile plutonium-$239$. $\rm{^{238}U}$ cannot support a chain reaction because inelastic scattering reduces neutron energy below the range where fast fission of one or more next-generation nuclei is probable.

When they come into contact with the neutrons, they are either absorbed or reflected. If they are fast/slow enough they are absorbed and $\rm{_{92}^{238}U} + \rm{_{1}^{0}n} \to \begin{cases} &\rm{_{92}^{239}U^{*}} \to \rm{_{92}^{239}U} + \gamma \to \dots\\ &\rm{_{92}^{239}U} \to \rm{_{93}^{239}Np} + \rm{_{-1}^{~~~0}\beta}\\ \end{cases}$ takes place. "$\rm{^{239}Np}$ further decays to plutonium-$239$ also through beta decay ($\rm{^{239}Np}$ has a half-life of about $2.35$6 days), in a second important step that ultimately produces fissile $\rm{^{239}Pu}$ (used in weapons and for nuclear power), from $\rm{^{238}U}$ in reactors." - Wikipedia about [Uranium-$239$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_uranium#Uranium-239)

So your theories are roughly correct.But even if the uranium-$238$ doesn't give out neutrons directly, the particles it decays into can give off neutrons, but the process takes some time and takes a little long in a bomb where everything happens in a minimally short time is pretty much useless.

**Last Question:**

As long as their concentration in the core is low, they are ok, but their chain reaction inhibitory properties make them sub-optimal in the core. $\rm{^{238}U}$ cannot support a chain reaction because inelastic scattering reduces neutron energy below the range where fast fission of one or more next-generation nuclei is probable aka they are just stealing the place of the needed $\rm{^{235}U}$. So it would be better if it wasn't absorbing, but still not optimal at its core. However, it would then be particularly good in the reflector.

However, they also potentially occur in other parts of the nuclear bomb:

> Most modern nuclear weapons utilize $\rm{^{238}U}$ as a "tamper" material (see nuclear weapon design). A tamper which surrounds a fissile core works to reflect neutrons and to add inertia to the compression of the $\rm{^{239}U}$ charge. -Wikipedia about [$\rm{^{238}U}$ in nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238#Nuclear_weapons)